# OpsWorks: adding an SSH key via Chef to be used by Composer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssh, composer-php

We are currently migrating the deployment process of our PHP applications to AWS OpsWorks. I am writing a custom Chef recipe to update all Composer dependencies on each Deploy event (that is, `composer update`), but one of our dependencies is hosted in a private BitBucket repository of our own.

I would like to execute an `ssh-add` command so that the SSH key can be used by Composer. What is the correct way to accomplish this?